# Seems impossible to delete a subscription in CloudKit? `-deleteSubscriptionWithID` always returns true

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications, cloudkit

I'm hoping there's an experienced CloudKit guru out there, but based off my google search queries, I'm not sure if you exist.  I think this may be a bug with Apple, but I can't be sure :\

I can save a subscription to my `CKDatabase` fine, no problems at all.

```
[publicDatabase saveSubscription:subscription completionHandler:^(CKSubscription *subscription, NSError *error) {
    if (error)
    {
        //No big deal, don't do anything.
    }
    else
    {
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:[subscription subscriptionID] forKey:@"SUBSCRIPTION"];
    }
}];
```

Whenever I change a field in my record, I get a push notification, and everything is happy.

My problem is removing this subscription.

I have tried calling [`-deleteSubscriptionWithID:completionHandler:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/CloudKit/Reference/CKDatabase_class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/CKDatabase/deleteSubscriptionWithID:completionHandler:)
As you can see in the above code snippet, I save off the subscription ID (Have also confirmed it to be the correct subscription ID by calling `-fetchAllSubscriptionsWithCompletionHandler:`

I passed the subscriptionID in that message, like so:

```
[publicDatabase deleteSubscriptionWithID:[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"SUBSCRIPTION"] completionHandler:^(NSString * _Nullable subscriptionID, NSError * _Nullable error) {
    if( error ) {
        NSLog(@"ERROR: %@", [error description] );
    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"SUCCESS: %@", subscriptionID);
    }
}];
```

But it doesn't delete my subscription:
[image]

And no matter what I pass as the subscriptionID, there is no error and I see "SUCCESS" upon "deleting".

[image]
[image]

...so yeah.  Clearly that isn't going to work.

If I manually delete the subscription through the Cloudkit Dashboard, my `-fetch` call properly notices that and returns an empty array:
[image]

So at this point I'm certain that I'm either deleting a subscription incorrectly in code, or it's broken and (not likely) nobody has asked on SO or any other forum that I can find?

I have also tried using a [`CKModifySubscriptionsOperation`](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/CloudKit/Reference/CKModifySubscriptionsOperation_class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/CKModifySubscriptionsOperation/initWithSubscriptionsToSave:subscriptionIDsToDelete:)

```
   CKModifySubscriptionsOperation *deleteSub = [[CKModifySubscriptionsOperation alloc] initWithSubscriptionsToSave:nil subscriptionIDsToDelete:@[[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"SUBSCRIPTION"]]];
   [publicDatabase addOperation:deleteSub];
```

No results :(

Answer (score 6):

I delete subscriptions using the database.deleteSubscriptionWithID function.

If you want to make sure that the ID is correct you could also first fetch all of them using `database.fetchAllSubscriptionsWithCompletionHandler({subscriptions, error in`

Then in the completion handler check if it's a valid subscription using: `if let  subscription: CKSubscription = subscriptionObject`

And then delete one or more using: `database.deleteSubscriptionWithID(subscription.subscriptionID, completionHandler: {subscriptionId, error in`

Here you can see code how I delete all subscriptions:
https://github.com/evermeer/EVCloudKitDao/blob/1bfa936cb46c5a2ca75f080d90a3c02e925b7e56/AppMessage/AppMessage/CloudKit/EVCloudKitDao.swift#L897-897